# Error checking for subterfuge update on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to run subterfuge on ubuntu. I downloaded and installed the latest software but when I try to run it I get this Message

> Subterfuge courtesy of r00t0v3rr1d3 & 0sm0s1z
>   Checking for updates. You can disable this feature through the settings page.
>   sh: 1: /usr/share/subterfuge/manage.py: not found

Comment: Manage.py is in the subterfuge folder but when i open /usr/share/subterfuge it is not in there so how do i move it into there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that the file `/usr/share/subterfuge/manage.py` doesn't exist. This is likely because you installed subterfuge elsewhere on your machine.

Their [source code](https://github.com/Subterfuge-Framework/Subterfuge/blob/6c35097c202ee2c23fa68ab966711c9cf9300c95/update.py#L70) has a number of hard-coded paths (for whatever reason) that require a specific installation directory.

I would copy your installation over to the directory in which they expect it to be

```
sudo cp -r /old/installation_dir/subterfuge/* /usr/share/subterfuge
```

Comment: When i try to put in the manage.py file into /usr/share/subterfuge it says that i am not the owner and i can not access it so how do i add it

Comment: @JohnKaruntzos You need to copy the *entire* subterfuge installation to `/usr/share/subterfuge`. You will need to use `sudo` to perform this action

Comment: I apologize i am very new on this software. How would i do that

Comment: I typed that in and it said

Comment: Cp: missing destination file operand after '/old/installation_dir/subterfuge/*usr/share/subterfuge '

Comment: @JohnKaruntzos 1) Substitute your current installation directory in for the first part 2) add a space between that and the destination directory. it's not one long string...

Comment: I typed in sudo cp -r /Desktop/subterfuge/* /usr/share/subterfuge

Comment: Don't you want `~/Desktop/subterfuge/*`?

Comment: It gave me this... Cp: cannot stat '/Desktop/subterfuge/*': no such file or directory

Comment: The installation file is on my desktop

Comment: @JohnKaruntzos Look at my comment above. You need the `~` in your path.

Comment: OK I put that in and nothing came up just the line to type came up again

Comment: @JohnKaruntzos Go look in `/usr/share/subterfuge`. All the files should be in there. Now start the app from *that* folder rather than the one on your desktop

Comment: Okay so subterfuge is now running. But when I hit start it says subterfuge will attempt to auto configure your network settings. You can turn off auto configure in the settings tab. And then it doesn't start

Comment: @JohnKaruntzos That is a different question and would need it's own question post. This question was specifically about the error that you were seeing and it seems that we have resolved that issue.

Comment: Yes thank you very much for your help I really appreciate it

Comment: @JohnKaruntzos You're welcome. Please consider marking this as the solution